# SQL update working not insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Ok I am going to do my best describing this.  I have a SP which passes in XML and updates and inserts another table.  This was working yesterday.  All I changed today was loading the temp table with a OPENXML vs xml.nodes.  I even changed it back and I am still getting this interesting issue.  I have an update and insert in the same transaction.  The update works and then the Insert hangs, no error no nothing... going on 9 minutes.  Normally takes 10 seconds.  No Blocking processes according to `master.sys.sysprocesses`.  The funny thing is the Select of the Insert returns no rows as they are already in the database.  The update updates 72438  in

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1359 ms,  elapsed time = 7955 ms.

ROWS AFFECTED(72438)
```

I am out of ideas as to what could be causing my issue? Permissions I don't think so?  Space I don't think so because a Error would be returned?

queries:

```
UPDATE [Sales].[dbo].[WeeklySummary]
SET [CountryId] = I.CountryId
    ,[CurrencyId] = I.CurrencyId
    ,[WeeklySummaryType] = @WeeklySummaryTypeId       
    ,[WeeklyBalanceAmt] = M.WeeklyBalanceAmt + I.WeeklyBalanceAmt
    ,[CurrencyFactor] = I.CurrencyFactor
    ,[Comment] = I.Comment
    ,[UserStamp] = I.UserStamp
    ,[DateTimeStamp] = I.DateTimeStamp
FROM 
    [Sales].[dbo].[WeeklySummary] M
INNER JOIN
    @WeeklySummaryInserts I
    ON M.EntityId = I.EntityId
    AND M.EntityType = I.EntityType
    AND M.WeekEndingDate = I.WeekEndingDate
    AND M.BalanceId = I.BalanceId
    AND M.ItemType = I.ItemType
    AND M.AccountType = I.AccountType
```

and

```
INSERT INTO [Sales].[dbo].[WeeklySummary]
    ([EntityId]
    ,[EntityType]
    ,[WeekEndingDate]
    ,[BalanceId]
    ,[CountryId]
    ,[CurrencyId]
    ,[WeeklySummaryType]
    ,[ItemType]
    ,[AccountType]
    ,[WeeklyBalanceAmt]
    ,[CurrencyFactor]
    ,[Comment]
    ,[UserStamp]
    ,[DateTimeStamp])
SELECT
    I.[EntityId]
,   I.[EntityType]
,   I.[WeekEndingDate]
,   I.[BalanceId]
,   I.[CountryId]
,   I.[CurrencyId]
,   @WeeklySummaryTypeId
,   I.[ItemType]
,   I.[AccountType]
,   I.[WeeklyBalanceAmt]
,   I.[CurrencyFactor]
,   I.[Comment]
,   I.[UserStamp]
,   I.[DateTimeStamp]
FROM 
    @WeeklySummaryInserts I
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Sales].[dbo].[WeeklySummary] M
    ON I.EntityId = M.EntityId
    AND I.EntityType = M.EntityType
    AND I.WeekEndingDate = M.WeekEndingDate
    AND I.BalanceId = M.BalanceId
    AND I.ItemType = M.ItemType
    AND I.AccountType = M.AccountType
WHERE M.WeeklySummaryId IS NULL
```

**UPDATE**

Trying the advice here worked for a while I run the following before my stored procedure call

```
UPDATE STATISTICS Sales.dbo.WeeklySummary;
UPDATE STATISTICS Sales.dbo.ARSubLedger;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.AccountBalance;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.InvoiceUnposted
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.InvoiceItemUnposted;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.InvoiceItemUnpostedHistory;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.InvoiceUnpostedHistory;
EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.proc_ChargeRegister'
```

Still stalling at the Insert Statement, which again inserts 0 rows.

Comment: Does the insert hang if you comment out the update?

Comment: No theory on your specific issue but if you are on SQL Server 2008 you might want to use `MERGE` for this anyway.

Comment: So what I actually did is delete the data I was updating.  The first attempt 0 updates and all inserts and it worked fine.  The second time all updates and 0 inserts and it worked fine now.  Any ideas?  Should I delete the question.  I am now scared this will happen in production some day.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but its 2005.  I should have specified.

Comment: @Mike - What does `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` show for that session when it is hung?

Comment: @Mike The symptoms strike me as the execution plan not being evaluated as it has in the past either due to increased index fragmentation or statistics not being updated. Have you evaluated the execution plan of the update and insert? Whats the condition (fragmentation) of the indexes? How about the statistics? Is either statement scanning (instead of seeking) when you execute the process in normal conditions?

Comment: @Mike - I am inclined to agree with @artosql. Do you have the right indexes on all the fields you are joining on? Did you see the execution plan? Can you run 'sp_what' while this is running, and see if any processes are blocked, and see if you can check you process and make sure its not blocking itself?

Comment: does the select clause of your insert statement hang as well when issued as a query on its own ?

Comment: Can you post your entire SP create/alter script?  Does the sql run fine all the time when you execute it in a query window?  One issue is the SP might be running poorly due to its habit of parameter sniffing.  XML parameters seem to cause issues with parameter sniffing.  One thing you might try is recompiling the SP and running it again with the same data and see if it works.  If so, then you might consider storing all your parameters in local variables.

Comment: Thanks Everyone, Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the behavior after I deleted the data from the table but I will keep your suggestions in mind I did run sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks but all that showed up where server related things like LAZY WRITER nothing I seem to recognize.

Comment: @Mike - Since this question is resolved, I would suggest that you close it out or delete it.  That way it doesn't sit open and unresolved.  Since work was done on the issue and it might occur again, I would suggest that you answer your own question and accept the answer.  That way people can benefit from the above helpful comments.

Comment: Unfortunally this issue has come up again, see the edit.  Or should I close this and open a new question?

Comment: Have you tried MAXDOP 1 on the INSERST statement?  What about the waiting tasks that might display some kind of intersting wait?

Comment: Paul, I have not tried MaxDop but in looking at the query plan I see that some one removed my indexs and it is defaulting back to a nested loop join.  After I get that "issue" resolved I will check back.

Comment: As requested before: we need to see the entire stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really only a few things that can be going on, and the trick here is to eliminate them in order, from simplest to most complex.

STEP 1: Hand craft a set of XML to run that will produce exactly one insert and no updates, so you can go "back to basics" as it were and establish that the code is still doing what you expect, and the result is exactly what you expect.  This may seem silly or unnecessary but you really need this reality check to start.

STEP 2: Hand craft a set of XML that will produce a medium-size set of inserts, still with no updates.  Based on your experience with the routine, try to find something that will run in a 3-4 seconds.  Perhaps 5000 rows.  Does it continue to behave as expected?

STEP 3: Assuming steps 1 and 2 pass easily, the next most likely problem is TRANSACTION SIZE.  If your update hits 74,000 rows in a single statement, then SQL Server must allocate resources to be able to roll back all 74,000 rows in the case of an abort.  Generally you should assume the resources (and time) required to maintain a transaction explode exponentially as the row count goes up.  So hand-craft one more set of inserts that contains 50,000 rows.  You should find it takes dramatically more time.  Let it finish.  Is it 10 minutes, an hour?  If it takes a long time but finishes, you have an issue with TRANSACTION SIZE, the server is choking trying to keep track of everything required to roll back the insert in the event of failure.

STEP 4: Determine if your entire stored procedure is operating within a single implied transaction.  If it is, the matter is entirely worse, because SQL Server is tracking together everything required to roll back both the 74,000 updates and the ??? inserts in a single transaction.  See this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687099(v=vs.85).aspx

STEP 5: If you've got a single implicit transaction, you can either.  A) Turn that off, which may help some but will not entirely fix the problem, or B) break the sproc into two separate calls, one for updates, one for inserts, so that at least the two are in separate transactions.

STEP 6: Consider "chunking".  This is a technique for avoiding exploding transaction costs.    Considering just the INSERT to get us started, you wrap the insert into a loop that begins and commits a transaction inside each iteration, and exits when affected rows is zero.  The INSERT is modified so that you pull only the first 1000 rows from the source and insert them (that 1000 number is kind of arbitrary, you may find 5000 produces better performance, you have to experiment a bit).  Once the INSERT affects zero rows, there are no more rows to handle and the loop exits.

QUICK EDIT: The "chunking" system works because the complete throughput for a large set of rows looks something like a quadratic.  If you execute an INSERT that affects a huge number of rows, the total time for all rows to be handled explodes.  If on the other hand you break it up and go row-by-row, the overhead of opening and committing each statement causes the total time for all rows to explode.  Somewhere in the middle, when you've "chunked" out 1k rows per statement, the transaction requirements are at their minimum and the overhead of opening and committing the statement is negligible, and the total time for all rows to be handled is a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the stored proc was actually getting recompiled in the middle of running because it was deleting rows from a temp table.  My situation doesn't look like yours, but mine was so odd that reading about it might give you some ideas.

[Unexplained SQL Server Timeouts and Intermittent Blocking](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/02/24/Unexplained-SQL-Server-Timeouts-and-Intermittent-Blocking.aspx)

I think you should post the full stored proc because the problem doesn't look to be where you think it is.